# Python - mock imported dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, mocking, patch

At the top of the code I want to test I have an import like:

```
from resources import RESOURCES
```

where `RESOURCES` is a dictionary of values.

How can I mock it in the test?

What I would like to is, no matter what is in the real module, return a well known dictionary.

For example in one test I want `RESOURCES` to be:

```
{
  'foo': 'bar'
}
```

while in another test I want it to be:

```
{
  'something': 'else'
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mock it"?

Comment: How well do you need to "mock" it. Do you need to test the module is there, do you need to fake the module is there? Do you just need a `RESOURCES` definition, or do you need a fake entry in `sys.modules`?

Comment: You can add a local (that is same directory) module `resources.py` which contains your mock `RESOURCES` dictionary. Or you can place that module somewhere else and prepend the corresponding path to `sys.path`: `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/resources/')`.

Comment: there isn't any way to achieve it with `unittest.mock`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way I made it to `patch` the `RESOURCE` object is using:

```
from default import RESOURCES
from mock import patch

with patch.dict(RESOURCES, {'foo': 'bar'}, clear=True):
    assert(RESOUCES['foo'], 'bar')
```

Note that you'll need to import the dictionary you want to patch in the test suite

It's also possible to use the decorator syntax:

```
from default import RESOURCES
from mock import patch

@patch.dict(RESOURCES, {'foo': 'bar'}, clear=True)
def test(self):
    self.assert(RESOUCES['foo'], 'bar')
```

Comment: this leaks to other test cases. Use with extreme caution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [unittest.mock.patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock).  I think that it will meet your needs.