# How to mock os.environ['key'] using mockito with python?

Tags: python, mockito, python-mock

I can use python mockito to mock `os.environ.get('SOME_VAR')` as demo [here](https://github.com/namgivu/python-mock-start/blob/master/tests/test_210606_mockito_envvar/test_210606_mockito_envvar.py#L22).

Main idea

```
when(os.environ).get(...).thenReturn(MOCKED_VAL)
```

Though to mock `os.environ['SOME_VAR']` syntax, I failed to get it working as [this](https://github.com/namgivu/python-mock-start/blob/master/tests/test_210606_mockito_envvar/test_210606_mockito_envvar.py#L46) code.

p.s.

[My google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20mockto%20mock%20dict&oq=python%20mockto%20mock%20dict&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.3505j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results little helpful so I asked here.

The closest I can found is using [built-in unittest.path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44931447/248616) ie  `patch.dict(SOMEDICT, {'k':'v'}, clear=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no answer until today using mockito package.

Here is my solution using builtin unittest mock patch

```
 class TestSomething:

    def test_07_env_production_on(self):
        """mock to force ENVIRONMENT to be production"""
        from unittest.mock import patch
        p = patch.dict(in_dict=os.environ, values={'ENVIRONMENT': 'production'}, clear=False)
        p.start()
        self.addCleanup(p.stop)  # register mockito's unstub() method to unittest's cleanup
```